# error message: "Cannot split, erase or overlay with points, collection, Text or layout frame objects" in Mapbasic

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

In order to automate procedures using MapBasic, I wrote the code for overlapping two objects -- one a polygon object and the other a point object -- using Objects Intersect  statement written below.
It gives me the above mentioned error.

But actually, when I manually do the intersect via Mapinfo application (via Table\Update) it gives me a result which is a modified target table (BB.TAB).

```
'Open the point table
Open Table "C:\Temp\AA.TAB" Interactive

'Setting the Target
Select * from BB
Set Target On

Select * from AA

Objects Intersect Into Target Data CC=CC,DD=DD
```

How can I rectify Mapbasic error ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by intersecting a point with a polygon? Are you wanting to filter out the points to only points which fall within the polygons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you open the MapBasic window (Options > Show MapBasic window) and then perform the action again using the Table > Update Column menu item.

You can then see the actual statement used in the MapBasic window which will be using the "Add Column" statement